# Hello, Day 1 of Learning to Code For University

Tags: c#

I am trying to multiply a decimal but I am getting an error.

The child ticket is 50% of the cost of the Adult ticket. And the Seniors ticket is 70% of the Adult ticket. Error is telling me that the * operator cannot be applied to doubles or multiples..

I tried to use brackets to isolate the caculation.. but I am still getting the operand error.

```
Console.Write("Enter the cost of one Adult ticket: $");
decimal CostAdult = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

decimal revenue1 = CostAdult * Adult;
Console.WriteLine("You have made " + revenue1.ToString("C") + " for Adult ticket sales!");
Console.ReadLine();

decimal revenue2 = CostAdult * Child * 0.5;
Console.WriteLine("You have made " + revenue1.ToString("C") + " for Senior ticket sales!");
Console.ReadLine();

decimal revenue3 = CostAdult * Senior * 0.7;
Console.WriteLine("You have made " + revenue1.ToString("C") + " for Senior ticket sales!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: _Error is telling me that the * operator cannot be applied to doubles or multiples.._ - you will always get better answers if you include **the actual error message** rather than your interpretation of it.

Comment: According to [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals): _The type of a real literal is determined by its suffix as follows: The literal without suffix or with the d or D suffix is of type double. The literal with the f or F suffix is of type float. The literal with the m or M suffix is of type decimal._ Also see [Built-in types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add M after the value when assigning an decimal.

`decimal revenue = 0.5M;`

Comment: "after assigning" is incorrect terminology. You are adding an "m" _suffix_ to a literal to create a _decimal literal_.

Comment: Sorry! I'm from the netherlands. Sometimes I mess things up... :)

Comment: *"when assigning an [sic] decimal"* is still wrong. If you're assigning a decimal that's not a literal decimal expression, the suffix is irrelevant. The suffix specifically has to do with the literal value. Whether you're assigning to something or passing it as a parameter doesn't matter.